# misplaced foreign keys when using abstract classes and fluent api

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first, fluent-interface

I've a problem mapping foreign keys to the correct table when using abstract classes. Here's my model :

```
public abstract class Entity
{
    public Guid UID { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Product : Entity
{
    public DeviceModel Model { get; set; }
    public User Operator { get; set; }
}

public abstract class OrderEntry : Entity
{
    public Order Order { get; set; }
}

public class Device : Product
{
    public String Reference { get; set; }
    public String Serial { get; set; }
    public String SoftwareVersion { get; set; }
}

public class OrderEntryDevice : OrderEntry
{
    public DeviceModel Model { get; set; }
}
```

And the fluent api configurations (TPT schema) :

```
public class EntityConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Entity>
{
    public EntityConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("Entities");

        HasKey(t => t.UID);
    }
}

public class ProductConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Product>
{
    public ProductConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("Products");

        HasOptional(t => t.Operator)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(t => t.MapKey("FK_Operator"))
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}

public class OrderEntryConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<OrderEntry>
{
    public OrderEntryConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("OrderEntries");

        HasRequired(t => t.Order)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(t => t.MapKey("FK_Order"))
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}

public class DeviceConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Device>
{
    public DeviceConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("Devices");

        Property(t => t.Reference)
            .IsRequired();

        Property(t => t.Serial)
            .IsRequired();

        HasRequired(t => t.Model)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(t => t.MapKey("FK_Model"))
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}

public class OrderEntryDeviceConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<OrderEntryDevice>
{
    public OrderEntryDeviceConfiguration()
    {
        ToTable("OrderEntriesDevice");

        HasRequired(t => t.Model)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(t => t.MapKey("FK_Model"))
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

Creation of the database will put the "FK_Operator" foreign key in the "Products" table (exactly where I want it) but the "FK_Order" foreign key is placed in the "Entities" table instead of "OrderEntries" table. If I change the abstract property of class "OrderEntry" to concrete, then everything is OK. Do I have to avoid abstract class int this case ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried your model and I cannot reproduce the problem. I get the `FK_Order` column in the `OrderEntries` table and not in `Entities` table - as expected.

You can copy the following into `Program.cs` of a console app (also add `EntityFramework.dll` and `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll` to references).

I have created three dummy classes for `User`, `DeviceModel` and `Order` to get the code compiled and running. But the other classes are a copy from your question.

The question is: Where is the important difference between the code below and your code which could cause the wrong mapping you have?

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace EFAbstractTest
{
    public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid UID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class DeviceModel
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid UID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Order
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid UID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class Entity
    {
        public Guid UID { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class Product : Entity
    {
        public DeviceModel Model { get; set; }
        public User Operator { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class OrderEntry : Entity
    {
        public Order Order { get; set; }
    }

    public class Device : Product
    {
        public String Reference { get; set; }
        public String Serial { get; set; }
        public String SoftwareVersion { get; set; }
    }

    public class OrderEntryDevice : OrderEntry
    {
        public DeviceModel Model { get; set; }
    }

    public class EntityConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Entity>
    {
        public EntityConfiguration()
        {
            ToTable("Entities");

            HasKey(t => t.UID);
        }
    }

    public class ProductConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Product>
    {
        public ProductConfiguration()
        {
            ToTable("Products");

            HasOptional(t => t.Operator)
                .WithMany()
                .Map(t => t.MapKey("FK_Operator"))
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        }
    }

    public class OrderEntryConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<OrderEntry>
    {
        public OrderEntryConfiguration()
        {
            ToTable("OrderEntries");

            HasRequired(t => t.Order)
                .WithMany()
                .Map(t => t.MapKey("FK_Order"))
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        }
    }

    public class DeviceConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Device>
    {
        public DeviceConfiguration()
        {
            ToTable("Devices");

            Property(t => t.Reference)
                .IsRequired();

            Property(t => t.Serial)
                .IsRequired();

            HasRequired(t => t.Model)
                .WithMany()
                .Map(t => t.MapKey("FK_Model"))
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        }
    }

    public class OrderEntryDeviceConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<OrderEntryDevice>
    {
        public OrderEntryDeviceConfiguration()
        {
            ToTable("OrderEntriesDevice");

            HasRequired(t => t.Model)
                .WithMany()
                .Map(t => t.MapKey("FK_Model"))
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        }
    }

    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Entity> Entities { get; set; }
        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<DeviceModel> DeviceModels { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Order> Orders { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new EntityConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new ProductConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new OrderEntryConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new DeviceConfiguration());
            modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new OrderEntryDeviceConfiguration());
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (var ctx = new MyContext())
            {
                // some query, just to trigger database creation
                ctx.Orders.Count();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The only big difference between your context and mine can be found in the dbset you define : I only defined the entities dbset, not the others. I'll try adding some dbset as soon as I get back to work.

Comment: OK, it seems the creation of a dbset for each abstract class is the solution. Otherwise, I assume that the mapping using "ToTable" will go through the inheritance hierarchy until he founds the first abstract class with a corresponding dbset. I tagged your post as an answer, thanks again.